# android sdk google analytics track events with metadata

Tags: android, google-analytics

in the link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events

google explains how to send events. 
However I didn't see any mention of a way to send events with extra  pairs. 
for example if I want to send an event of uploading images, and I would like to also send something like
    <"number_of_images_uploaded", 4>
    <"location_of_upload", "Italy">
    <"was_registered_user", false>

etc..

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Apparently you can do it with custom dimensions**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

<strike>Can't do it. The link you provided shows that you can only send events with categories, actions, labels, and values.</strike>

The only way to store this meta data in combination with google analytics is to do it yourself.

e.g.

1. Send an HTTP request to your own server to create a record (or records) in a database with the meta information and return an identifier in the response.
2. When you receive a response from the server, send the google analytics event information to google along with your event ID that you received from your server.

This allows you to use google analytics for general user-interaction information and also allows you to link specific events in google analytics to their metadata on your server.